# How to enable irb tab completion in jruby

Tags: jruby, irb

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this, but I can't get the tab completion working in jRuby's irb on windows. If I ssh to the linux machine, irb works as expected, but in windows I just get tabs.

I have tried adding the following to my .irbrc (taken from the old questions on SO):

```
#require 'irb/completion'
#ARGV.concat [ "--readline", "--prompt-mode", "simple" ]

#IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
#IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
#IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] = []  unless IRB.conf.key?(:LOAD_MODULES)
#unless IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES].include?('irb/completion')
#  IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] << 'irb/completion'
#end

#require 'irbtools'

#require 'bond'
```

None of these things work. I've confirmed the .irbrc is working. I've tried both regular console and powershell. I'm blaming this on windows right now, but I honestly don't have a clue what's really going on or how to fix it.

I'm using jRuby 1.7 and Win7 x64 if any of that makes a difference.

### Additional

Spent some more time playing with it. I've now tried ansicon, pry, and ConEmu with no luck. I'm starting to think the problem may be with jRuby 1.7 - next thing to try is see if I have the same problem on 1.6.8 - but that's more than I can mess with for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug with JRuby 1.7.0 - in JRuby 1.6.8 the tab completion worked fine once I did `require 'irb/completion'`

logged the bug under http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6996